# Generate Excel with macros jusing JAVA

Tags: java, macros

Hi I'm trying to generate an excel using java.  Here I want to add macros to the same excel file while generating.  I went through some post in `stackoverflow` but didn't find exact answer.

Can anyone please give me some sample code for generating excel with macros using java (I'm using Apache poi jar file for generating excel)

Comment: We cant do it in java

Comment: my project is based on java only so i have to do it by java.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [documentation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/limitations.html) says this

> - Macros
>
> Macros can not be created. The are currently no plans to support
>   macros. However, reading and re-writing files containing macros will
>   safely preserve the macros.